# Python - Syntax error with values

Tags: python, syntax

I'm trying to create a program in Python that gets a users price and a discount. If the discountCode is either 1 or 2, it should deduce 10% from the original cost. However, when I try and execute it, the code does not seem to work. I have tried <=1 or >=2 and 1,2 but nothing seems to work and returns a syntax error. Am I over-seeing something here?

```
#Pseudocode

#User inputPrice and discountCode
#If discountCode = 1 or 2:
#   outputPrice = (0.1 * inputPrice) - inputPrice
#else:
#   outputPrice = inputPrice
#print (outputPrice)

inputPrice = input ("What is the price of the product?\n")
discountCode = input ("What is your discount code?\n")

if discountCode 1,2:
    outputPrice = (0.1 * inputPrice) - inputPrice
elif discountCode not 1,2:
    outputPrice = inputPrice

print ("Your final total comes to\t", outputPrice)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `in` operator and wrap `1, 2` with parentheses:

```
inputPrice = int(input("What is the price of the product?\n"))
discountCode = int(input("What is your discount code?\n"))

if discountCode in (1, 2):
    outputPrice = (0.1 * inputPrice) - inputPrice
elif discountCode not in (1, 2):
    outputPrice = inputPrice

print ("Your final total comes to\t", outputPrice)
```

And you don't actually need the `if ... elif` statement:

```
inputPrice = int(input("What is the price of the product?\n"))
discountCode = int(input("What is your discount code?\n"))

if discountCode in (1, 2):
    outputPrice = (0.1 * inputPrice) - inputPrice
else:
    outputPrice = inputPrice

print ("Your final total comes to\t", outputPrice)
```

Comment: I suspect that you also need to change `(0.1 * inputPrice) - inputPrice` to `inputPrice - (0.1 * inputPrice)` unless you would like to give a discount of 190%.

Comment: Cheers for the help, it worked! (Although I assume you guys wouldn't be surprised) And yes, I realised right after posting that I had my formula around the other way, but thanks again for pointing it out to others.

Answer (score 2):

You should cast your input as an `int` and also fix your `in` statements:

```
inputPrice = int(input ("What is the price of the product?\n"))
discountCode = int(input ("What is your discount code?\n"))

if discountCode in (1,2):
    outputPrice = (0.1 * inputPrice) - inputPrice
elif discountCode not in (1,2):
    outputPrice = inputPrice

print ("Your final total comes to\t", outputPrice)
```

Comment: because you missed the part with the invalid syntax...

Comment: Depending on the Python version, the values returned by `input()` may already be ints.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, However, it is always good practice to cast your input.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: In this case, the multiple-argument `print()` function call makes it more likely to be Python 3.

Comment: @sshashank124: It is better practice to not use `input()` or `eval()` in Python 2.

Comment: @Martijn, true, I missed that. Looks like Python 3 indeed.